# Анимация в iOS приложении

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Делаю тестовое приложение под iOS на `swift`.
Передо мной стоит **задача**:

В приложении нажимается кнопка старт - сверху падают геометрические фигуры. 
При сворачивании приложения - когда экран наполнился фигурами - должен приходить пуш о том, что область заполнилась фигурами.

Я так понимаю, что сначала надо разобраться с анимацией объектов, при этом надо прописать правило, по которому они не будут проваливаться друг в друга, а будут ложиться поверх. Далее надо написать правило по которому произойдет событие при достижении фигуры определенной верхней точки + разобраться с пушами.
Не могли бы подсказать с чего начать? В какую сторону копать вообще?
Можно ли сделать это с помощью `UIView` метода `animateWithDuration:animations:`?

Comment: дайте больше информации. это игра, или просто анимация типа фигура появилась сверху доползла до низа и там осталась навсегда?

Comment: В принципе это просто анимация. Фигуры с заданным промежутком времени появляются сверху и падают вниз в кучу. Как эта самая куча дорастает до верхней границы экрана приходит пуш.

Comment: подробнее, что такое куча? фигура появляется посередине и летит вниз, где становится на предыдущую фигуру, или упав может съехать в сторону чтоб получилась горка?

Comment: ну и сразу: пуш делать будет сложно - когда приложение уходит на бэкграунд его исполнение останавливается. есть варианты как его заставить работать, но я думаю это не правильно, когда анимация жрет ресурсы системы, хотя пользователь ее не видит.

Comment: Фигуры через определенный промежуток времени падают вниз из рандомных верхних положений с одинаковой координатой y и разной координатой x. Падают вниз, ударяются о фигуры, которые лежат внизу отскакивают и ложатся рядом/поверх. И так, пока фигуры не заполнят пространство экрана, после чего приходит пуш.

Comment: На практике это да, глупо так расходовать ресурсы. Но для теста желательно так сделать)

Answer (score 1):

Подобные вещи делаются с применением технологии UIDynamic

1. UICollisionBehavior — обеспечивает обнаружение столкновений
2. UIGravityBehavior — как понятно из названия, обеспечивает имитацию тяготения

Инициализируете UIGravityBehavior и добавьте к нему ваши вьюхи, которые должны падать сверху. Запускаете и все падает. Далее добавляете обнаружение столкновенийВот и все. Рандомом выбираете положение сверху для новой вьюхи и вперед!

```html
@interface ViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIDynamicAnimator *animator;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIGravityBehavior *gravity;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UICollisionBehavior *collision;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIView *view1 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50)];
    view1.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
    [self.view addSubview:view1];
    
    UIView *view2 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 480, 50, 50)];
    view2.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    [self.view addSubview:view2];
    
    self.animator = [[UIDynamicAnimator alloc] initWithReferenceView:self.view];
    self.gravity = [[UIGravityBehavior alloc] initWithItems:@[view1, view2]];
    [self.animator addBehavior:self.gravity];
    
    self.collision = [[UICollisionBehavior alloc] initWithItems:@[view1, view2]];
    self.collision.translatesReferenceBoundsIntoBoundary = YES;
    [self.animator addBehavior:self.collision];
    
}
```

Когда запустите, то увидите следующее:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я в итоге так и сделал это, спасибо!
Только не разобрался с тем, как остановить цикл падения фигур по достижению фигурами определенной верхней координаты. Вы не знаете на что можно обратить внимание?

Comment: У UIDynamicAnimatorDelegate есть два метода dynamicAnimatorWillResume и dynamicAnimatorDidPause. В них можно проверять координаты

Answer (score 0):

Ну попробуем:

1) падение фигур. Можно сделать через `animateWithDuraiton`, но я бы предложил посмотреть в сторону какого нибудь более серьезного решения типа SpriteKit или cocos2d. Есть смысл так же прикрутить физический движок типа box2d - сохранит вам время на все подсчеты что куда скатилось.

2)Пуш. Тут два варианта: либо требовать от системы, чтобы приложение продолжало работать на бэкграунде при помощи `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:` (тут надо помнить, что система может убить ваше приложение в любой момент, если ей понадобятся ресурсы), либо регистрироваться для выполнения на бэкграунде при помощи capabilities -> background modes. там ставите, например, что вы играете музыку на бэкграунде и спокойно выполняетесь сколько вам надо (в этом случае надо будет реально играть какой то звук, например, раз в минуту, а то эпл вас не пустит в аппстор).

Второй вариант просчитывать все падения фигур заранее, определять сколько времени это займет и ставить локальное уведомление через это время. когда пользователь вернется в приложение показывать ему финальное состояние всей системы.